# Об n-арных союзах русского языка

Tags: союзы

Предположим на столике лежат туз, король, дама и валет.

Какие 4-арные союзы русского языка употреблены в указаниях:

- "Возьми и туза, и короля, и даму, и валета.",
- "Не бери ни туза, ни короля, ни даму, ни валета.",
- "Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета.",
- "Не бери или туза, или короля, или даму, или валета."?

P.S. Дорогие филологи, я побоялся сформулировать свой вопрос так: "Какие союзы русского языка с плавающей арностью (местностью) употреблены в указаниях: ... ?"

Comment: Правильно: Не бери ни туза, ни короля, ни даму, ни валета. Нарушаете правила.

Comment: 1) Возьми  все  карты.  2) Не  бери  ни  одной  карты.  3) Возьми  одну  карту ( любую ).  4) Возьми  три  карты.  Вот  смысл  указаний,  если  карты  лежат  рубашками  вниз.  Если  же  рубашками  вверх,  первое  указание  не  имеет  смысл  №1.  А  для  других  указаниЙ  смысл  появляется,  если  угадывающий  не  знает   какие  карты  перед  ним.       Что  такое  4-арные  союзы ?

Comment: Благодарю за предоставленные сведения.

Answer (score 1):

Да, действительно, что такое 4-арные союзы? Может, 4-ых парные? Но и тогда не ясно о чем речь.